# Collection items aren't displayed in design view

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

Can someone help me understand why my design view doesn't display Dog, Cat, and Horse, but instead is just showing three 0 and CommonName in the list view? The list view is populated with the correct data once I just the app, however it isn't working in design view.

Here's what it looks like
[image]

ViewModel Code:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Animal> Animals { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Animals.sqlite");

        db.CreateTable<Animal>();

        if (db.Table<Animal>().Count() == 0)
        {
            initCollection();
        }
    }

    private void initCollection()
    {
        Animals.Clear();

        Animals.Add(new Animal() { ID = 0, CommonName = "Dog" });
        Animals.Add(new Animal() { ID = 1, CommonName = "Cat" });
        Animals.Add(new Animal() { ID = 2, CommonName = "Horse" });
    }
}
```

Animal class:

```
public class Animal
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CommonName { get; set; }
}
```

In XAML is set a reference to ViewModel

```
xmlns:vm="using:Module3_SQLite.ViewModels"
```

I then set DataContext

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

And here's the list view

```
<ListView x:Name="lvCollectionItems" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Width="500" Height="200" Margin="0,10,0,10">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="0,0,40,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here's a complete page XAML in case you need it:

```
<Page x:Class="Module3_SQLite.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:vm="using:Module3_SQLite.ViewModels" 
      xmlns:local="using:Module3_SQLite.Views"
      mc:Ignorable="d" RequestedTheme="Dark">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Content="Main Page"
                             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                             RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" />

        <Grid 
            RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader" 
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
            Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock Text="Collection Items" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" />
                <ListView x:Name="lvCollectionItems" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Width="500" Height="200" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Margin="0,0,40,0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteSelected" Content="Delete Selected" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnClearList" Content="Clear List" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnLoadFromDB" Content="Load From DB" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnResetCollection" Content="Reset Collection" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Database Items" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" />
                <ListView x:Name="lvDatabaseItems" Width="500" Height="200" Margin="0,10,0,10">

                </ListView>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="btnSaveToDB" Content="Save Collection to DB" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteSelectedFromDB" Content="Delete Selected From DB" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteAllFromDB" Content="Delete All From DB" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Edit Selected Item" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" Width="70"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbName" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,50">
                    <TextBlock Text="ID:" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" Width="70" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbId" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Button x:Name="btnSaveToCollection" Content="Save To Collection" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                <Button x:Name="btnInsertToDB" Content="Insert into DB" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdateDB" Content="Update in DB" Margin="0,0,0,50" />

                <TextBlock Text="Modify Collection" FontSize="{ThemeResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10" >
                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" Width="70" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbItemNameCollection" Width="200"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <TextBlock Text="ID:" Width="70" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbItemIDCollection" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdateCollection" Content="Update" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="115" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add data source to list view programmatically? The only one way designer can see what is inside binded data, is to give it this data via design view. Whenever I was binding controls with data sources, I saw data in design view when I did it via control's pop-up menu. It's because designer cannot know what data is behind source unless it is connected to it (when you run your app and get data from db - but it's too late for the designer).